# Sort a list of lists with duplication constraint

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list where in each sub list the first element represents a product and the second a price:

```
my_list = [['a',100],['b',100],['a',75],['c',120],['a',400],['c',150]]
```

I want to sort by the price descending, but I want a product to repeat only after one of each product has already been seen.
In the example I have three distinct products: `'a', 'b', 'c'`
The ordering would then be:

```
sorted_list = [['a',400],['c',150],['b',100],['c',120],['a',100],['a',75]]
```

Is this possible in one pass?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in one pass, no.

Comment: Could you please clarify "I want a product to repeat only after one of each product has already been seen"? For instance, if the input list is `[['a', 2], ['a', 2], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 0], ['c', 0], ['c', 0]]`, then what would be the output?

Comment: @Stef output would be [['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['c', 0], ['a', 2],  ['b', 1],  ['c', 0], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['c', 0]]

Comment: @user263961 Then the code I wrote in my answer should work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by product, sort each product list separately, then interleave the lists.

Grouping is typically done with a dict of lists. Interleaving can be done with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```py
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
from operator import itemgetter

def interleave_sort(l, marker="__dummyvalue__"):
    # GROUPING
    groups = {}
    for product, price in l:
        groups.setdefault(product, []).append(price)
    for product_list in groups.values():
        product_list.sort(reverse=True)
    sublists = ([[product, price] for price in prices] for product, prices in groups.items())
    # INTERLEAVING
    _marker = (marker, 0)
    i = chain.from_iterable(sorted(r, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) for r in zip_longest(*sublists, fillvalue=_marker))
    return (x for x in i if x is not _marker)

print(list(interleave_sort([['a',100],['b',100],['a',75],['c',120],['a',400],['c',150]])))
# [['a', 400], ['c', 150], ['b', 100], ['c', 120], ['a', 100], ['a', 75]]

print(list(interleave_sort([['a', 2], ['a', 2], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 0], ['c', 0], ['c', 0]])))
# [['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['c', 0], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['c', 0], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['c', 0]]
```

Note that the last two lines, `i = ...` and `return...`, are adapted from [the source code of `more_itertools.interleave_longest`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#interleave_longest). I just added an extra `sorted(...)` in there to fit your requirements.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It doesn't look like one pass, so can't be interpreted as a "yes", but it also doesn't rule out that it's possible, so can't be interpreted as a "no", either. It's like they asked "Do you have coffee?" and you reply "Here's some tea".

Comment: @KellyBundy To expand on your "coffee" analogy, I think it's like they asked "Does this coffee machine work? When I press button A, my cup stays empty." and I reply "If you press button B, your cup will fill with delicious black coffee.". While it doesn't explain what button A is for, nor prove that the cup wouldn't fill with coffee if we pressed button A hard enough, it does answer the question "Can I get coffee with this coffee machine?".

Comment: @KellyBundy But if you insist, I can submit a new answer explaining why this is obviously impossible in one pass.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say your "expansion" of the analogy isn't really an analogy (of what they wrote). Because there you do answer the question. Your version is rather an analogy of "How can I do this sort? I can't find a one-pass way." (which isn't what they wrote).

Comment: @KellyBundy The question post is in two parts: First, a description of the problem. "I want to sort the price descending...". Then at the very end, just one short question: "Is this possible in one pass?" It seemed to me that that short question was more an afterthought or an additional question, and that the main question was "How to solve this problem?". In particular, the answer to the question "Is this possible in one pass?" is "No", but that's not a very helpful answer if they still want to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's possible they didn't ask the question they actually had. I'm trying to take questions seriously, though. Also bothers me when someone explicitly asks for an explanation of what's wrong with their attempt and then people completely ignore that and just post a completely different solution. I often downvote that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible in one pass?

No, in all generality this cannot be done in one pass.

This can be proven by reduction from the problem of sorting a list.

Consider the particular case where there is only one type of product:

```py
my_list = [['a', 1], ['a', 7], ['a', 9], ['a', 3], ['a', 5], ['a', 4], ['a', 8], ['a', 0], ['a', 6], ['a', 2]]
```

Then your problem is as hard as sorting the list. Sorting cannot be done in one pass in all generality; it requires at least `n log2(n)` operations, where `n` is the number of items in the list. [That's a theorem.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/proving-the-lower-bound-of-compares-in-comparison-based-sorting)

Comment: Depends on what they consider "one pass". They might mean one "pass" written by *themself*, and might for example consider `my_list.sort()` or any `my_list.sort(key=...)` to be one pass. But yeah, something like *"How do you imagine sorting in general in one pass?"* was my immediate reaction when I first saw the question.